# Relationship between 4 tables Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I need to show feeds with total comments, and total likes on that feed with the detail of users who have commented.

**Feeds Table**

```
| id | movie_id | user_id  | description | 
|----|----------|----------|-------------|
| 1  | 1        | 1        | Lorem Ipsum |
```

**Comments Table**

```
| id | feed_id | user_id  | comment   | 
|----|-------- |----------|-----------|
| 1  | 1       | 2        | comment 1 |
| 2  | 1       | 3        | comment 2 |
```

**Likes Table**

```
| id | feed_id | user_id  |
|----|-------- |----------|
| 1  | 1       | 2        |
| 2  | 1       | 3        |
```

**Users Table**

```
| id | username| email  |
|----|-------- |--------|
| 1  | a       | a@a.com|
| 2  | b       | b@b.com|
| 3  | c       | c@c.com|
```

**Relations**

`Feed.php`

```
public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function likes () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}

public function comments () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

`User.php`

```
public function feeds () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feed');
}

public function like () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Like');
}

public function comment () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
}
```

`Like.php`

```
public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function feed () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Feed');
}
```

`Comment.php`

```
public function user () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function feed () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Feed');
}
```

**Now I need to fetch all feeds (I have done with this), with comments count, likes count, and users details who have commented.**

**Ho can I get that in single query using Eloquent.**

Comment: you can't do that in single query using eloquent.. but you can do it in4 queries

Comment: I am working for mobile API that will be too slower if I will use 4 queries

Comment: it could be faster than 1 long query with joins.. you can easily test it, if you want to use joins than see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Comment: Can you show your controller code for getting the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$commentsCount = \App\Models\Comment::select('feed_id',\DB::raw('count(id) as comments_count'))->groupBy('feed_id')->toSql();
    $likesCount = \App\Models\Like::select('feed_id',\DB::raw('count(id) as likes_count'))->groupBy('feed_id')->toSql();
    $records = \DB::table('feeds as f')
            ->leftJoin('comments as c','f.id','=','c.feed_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as u','c.user_id','=','u.id')
            ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('('.$commentsCount.') as k'),'f.id','=','k.feed_id')
            ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('('.$likesCount.') as l'),'f.id','=','l.feed_id')
            ->select('f.id as fid','f.description','u.id as uid','u.name','u.email','k.comments_count','l.likes_count')
            ->orderBy('fid')
            ->get();

    $transform = function(array $records){
        $records = collect($records)->groupBy('fid');
        return $records->transform(function($items){
            $feed['id'] = $items->first()->fid;
            $feed['description'] = $items->first()->description;
            $feed['count'] = [
                'likes' => is_null($items->first()->likes_count) ? 0 : $items->first()->likes_count,
                'comments' => is_null($items->first()->comments_count) ? 0 : $items->first()->comments_count,
            ];
            $feed['users'] = $items->transform(function($user){
                return is_null($user->uid) ? [] : ['id'=>$user->uid,'name'=>$user->name,'email'=>$user->email];
            });

            return $feed;
        });
    };

    return array_values($transform($records)->toArray());
```

you can swap the closure function with other function. like

```
$this->transform($records);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access all those properties through the functions defined.

Example:

```
$feed = Feed::find($id);

foreach($feed->likes() as $like){
    echo $like->user()->get('username');
}
```

And so forth. Up to a point when you call ->get(), you are accessing an object, which can traverse all of these.